# Django Rest : failed to update custom user model with Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Please help me! I'm trying to update custom user model and here's what I'm doing.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="users", null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Gender_Choices, blank=True, null=True,)
```

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = ProfileSerializer(source='user')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_profile',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile' ,None)
        if user_profile_data is not None:
            instance.user_profile.profile_pic = user_profile_data['profile_pic']
            instance.user_profile.birthday = user_profile_data['birthday']
            instance.user_profile.gender = user_profile_data['gender']
            instance.user_profile.save()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

```
class ProfileAPI(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # make sure to catch 404's below
        obj = queryset.get(pk=self.request.user.id)
        return obj
```

after I did all this it now if I make a put request `{"user_profile":["This field is required."]`
and when tried to make a patch request it doesn't update at all. can you please help me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at you code i think is what you are trying to do is You made another model named Profile and linked it with django User model by using `OneToOneField`. Till here i understand and there is nothing wrong with it ... but i cannot get why you are using nested Serializer

If you just want to update the profile pic or other value you can just do like this

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_pic','birthday','gender']
```

and in you views :

```
class ProfileAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = request.user.profile() # see Below to see the comment
        serializer = UserUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data,partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'valid':True})
        else:
            return Response({'valid':False},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: Trying to get the profile of the User who requested to change the values. if you are getting errors saying cannot find profile then there must be an error at Your authentication or if you are not using an authentication

just send **user.id** or **profile.id** in url itself , access is via kwargs and then make a search using *Profile.objects.get(id = kwargs['id'])* or *User.objects.get(id = kwargs['id'])*

And if you are not trying to do this... then plz specify what you are trying to achive by using which method